# How i can secure ClientSecret for my app which i am using inside SharePoint asp.net console application

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, online

I have the following SharePoint asp.net console application, which runs each hour using windows tasks scheduler :-

```
string clientId = "e***";
string clientSecret = "****";
string sitename = "";
try
{

    using (var context = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
```

now i am not sure how i can secure my clientSecret inside my asp.net console application? can I encrypt the value and store it inside the console application app.config?

Answer (score 0):

DPAPI, which is what you're referring to by encrypting the value in app.config, is relatively weak. What I would suggest is storing the values in Azure KeyVault and use Certificate authentication to connect to KV.

Comment: I know that encrypting sections of the `app.config` might not be the best approach, but it is better than storing the client secret as plain text.. so can you advice how i can encrypt sections of the `app.config`?